# How to integrate $\int \frac{r^3}{(1+r^2)^4}?$

Tags: integration

How can I integrate $$\int \frac{r^3}{(1+r^2)^4}\mathrm{d}r?$$

I'm thinking I should expand the denominator using binomial theorem and then calculate the integral of the sum of the terms.

Is there a more efficient way to do this integral?

Comment: "I'm thinking I should expand the denominator using binomial theorem and then calculate the integral of the sum of the terms." -- This seems to be implying that

$$\frac{a}{b+c} = \frac a b + \frac a c$$

or something like that. That certainly won't work, since that's not how fractions work. It's why integrals with complicated denominators are some of the worst to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $u=r^2+1$ to get
$$\frac 12\int \frac{u-1}{u^4}\;\text{d}u$$
which can be tackled easily.

The final answer would be
$$-\dfrac{3r^2+1}{12r^6+36r^4+36r^2+12}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{r^3}{\left(1+r^2\right)^4} d r=&-\frac{1}{6} \int r^2 d\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+r^2\right)^3}\right] \\
= &- \frac{1}{6}\left[\frac{r^2}{\left(1+r^2\right)^3}-\frac{1}{\left(1+r^2\right)^3} d\left(r^2\right)\right] \quad \textrm{ (via IBP)}\\
= & -\frac{1}{6}\left[\frac{r^2}{6 \left(1+r^2\right)^3}+\frac{1}{2\left(1+r^2\right)^2}\right]+C \\
= & -\frac{3 r^2+1}{12\left(1+r^2\right)^3}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int \frac{r^3}{(1+r^2)^4}dr=\int\frac r{(1+r^2)^3}-\frac r{(1+r^2)^4}\ dr = \frac1{6(1+r^2)^3}-\frac1{4(1+r^2)^2}
\end{align}